# programa para calcular el promedio , la variacion por poblacion , y la desviacion estandar

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import math    
import time

print("\nCalcula el promedio, la varianza y desviacion estandar en 1 segundo!!!")

pregunta = int(input("\ncuantos numeros deseas introducir?: "))  
funcion = []

for x in range(pregunta):
    funcion.append(int(input("\nQue numeros vas a introducir?: ")))  # el int no se puede iterar, y si lo hago con *args solo me aceptara el ultimo numero y no todos ( lista si funciona )

for x in funcion:
    print(x)
    print(funcion)

def promedio(num):
    global t
    global p
    t = 0
    for arg in num:
        t+=arg
        p = t/pregunta
    print("\nEl promedio de los datos es:",p)

promedio(funcion)

# no entiendo la logica    ##############################################################################################

#def varianza_poblacion(num): # se operan mal los numeros
#   global r
  #  for arg in num:
   #     r = ((arg-p)**2 + (arg-p)**2 + (arg-p)**2) / pregunta  ## y si no son 3 numeros? ##
    #print("\nLa varianza de los datos es:",r)
#varianza_poblacion(funcion)

def varianza_poblacion(num):   ## se operan mal los numeros ##
    global r
    suma = 0
    for arg in num:
        r = (arg-p)**2
        suma += r # y si no son 3 numeros?
    print("\nLa varianza de los datos es:",suma)

varianza_poblacion(funcion)

##############################################################################################

def desviacion_estandar(num):
    r = math.sqrt(num)
    print("\nLa desviacion estandar de los datos es:",r)

desviacion_estandar(r)

time.sleep(10)
```

El problema es que la varianza no se calcula bien, y ademas,no se como hacer para que su calculo se efectue de acuerdo a el argumento ingresado ( datos ), si son 6 que haga la formula para los 6 datos ( y para cada dato ) etc. De momento solo sirve para 3 datos, y de paso calcula mal la varianza.

De resto, tanto el promedio, como la desviacion estandar estan bien, el error solo es en la varianza.

Apenas empiezo en este mundo , es tonto...
pero de verdad, ya no se que hacer :'v

Help me.

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] para aprender el funcionamiento del sitio y de paso ganes tu primera medalla, 
también es muy importante que leas [Ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que esta sea bien recibida por la comunidad y aquí te dejo un [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yo diría que tampoco hace bien la *desviación estándar*.

Como primer consejo: **nunca uses variables globales para devolver resultados**. Más aún, evita las variables globales en todo. Se pueden emplear para iniciar algún parámetro, pero para poco más.

Vayamos por partes: tenemos una lista de números que llamaremos `nums`. Para calcular el promedio:

```
def promedio(nums):
    return sum(nums) / len(nums)
```

Usamos dos funciones de python, `sum` y `len`, que nos devuelve la suma y el tamaño de una lista, respectivamente.

Una vez tenemos el promedio, la variancia sería:

```
def variancia(nums):
    p = promedio(nums)
    v = 0
    for x in nums:
        v += (x - p) ** 2
    return v / len(nums)
```

Una forma más corta usando compresiones de listas:

```
def variancia(nums):
    p = promedio(nums)
    return sum((x-p)**2 for x in nums) / len(nums)
```

Con la variancia, la desviación estándar es directa:

```
import math

def desviacion_estandar(nums):
    return math.sqrt(variancia(nums))
```

Falta comprobar que no se pasen listas vacías, algo que provocaría errores al dividir por cero.

Answer (score 0):

En Python 3 tenemos el modulo [`statistics`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/statistics.html), que puedes usar para calcular la media, desviación estándar y varianza:

```py
import statistics

valores = [ 1, 5, 9 , 13 ]
media = statistics.mean(valores) # 7
desviacion_estandar = statistics.stdev(valores) # 5.164...
varianza = statistics.variance(valores) # 26.666...
```

Documentación:
[Media](https://docs.python.org/3/library/statistics.html#statistics.mean), [desviación estándar](https://docs.python.org/3/library/statistics.html#statistics.stdev) y [varianza](https://docs.python.org/3/library/statistics.html#statistics.variance)